# Why is the text spacing messed up on my mobile website?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

My website works perfectly on [desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyLsW.jpg) and it works perfectly on the chrome desktop iphone [emulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt3t9.png), but the text spacing is messed up on the [mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvlLt.jpg) website on my phone. There is a random line break between the last two sentences in the top two circles and I don't know where that is coming from.

CSS File (the last media query, which is the one with a max width of 500px, gets activated when the screen is thinner than 500px, so that is the one I am using to layout the screen for mobile devices and for the desktop website when it is less than 500px wide):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #126DFF;
  color: #dadada;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 122vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #96c93d, #00b09b);
  position: relative;
}

.circles {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px 25px;
  border-spacing: 25px;
}

.left,
.middle,
.right {
  margin: auto 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  animation-name: anime;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

.text {
  background: radial-gradient( ellipse at center, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 70.3%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.text h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.text p {
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.25;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.text::before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  shape-outside: polygon( 0 0, 98% 0, 50% 6%, 23.4% 17.3%, 6% 32.6%, 0 50%, 6% 65.6%, 23.4% 82.7%, 50% 94%, 98% 100%, 0 100%);
  shape-margin: 7%;
}

.text p::before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  shape-outside: polygon( 2% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 2% 100%, 50% 94%, 76.6% 82.7%, 94% 65.6%, 100% 50%, 94% 32.6%, 76.6% 17.3%, 50% 6%);
  shape-margin: 7%;
}

.middle p {
  font-size: 22px;
}

@media (max-width: 1262px) and (min-width: 857px) {
  .right {
    margin-left: 212.5px;
  }
  .container {
    height: 150vh;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 857px) {
  .container {
    height: 200vh;
  }
  .left,
  .middle,
  .right {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 0px) {
  .left,
  .middle,
  .right {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
  .text p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .container {
    height: 160vh;
  }
  .middle {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .middle p br:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
  .middle p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">


    <div class="circles">

      <div class="left">
        <blockquote class="text">
          <h1><br>What we do?</h1>
          <p><br class="block"><br>We help small buisnesses build websites, write programs, and build databases.<br><br><br><br></p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>

      <div class="middle">
        <blockquote class="text">
          <h1><br>Why choose us?</h1>
          <p><br><br>We are an experienced team of students who possess a wide variety of skills and backgrounds. We colloborate with buisnesses and do our best to fulfil their requests while also honoring each and everyones input.<br><br></p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>

      <div class="right">
        <blockquote class="text">
          <h1><br>Social Media</h1>
          <p><br><img id="facebook" class="facebook" src="facebook.png" alt="facebook"><br><br><img class="instagram" src="instagram.png" alt="instagram"><br><br><img class="twitter" src="twitter.png" alt="twitter"></p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section></section>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve] for faster troubleshooting; CSS alone is not enough

Comment: @blurfus Ok i added a minimal reproducible example

Comment: `<p><br><br>`? Why? Use `padding` to get padding, not line breaks. Also, who or what are you quoting with the `blockquote`? Don't use elements for their default style; use CSS to style elements, use elements for their semantic meaning. Sorry, nothing to do with your actual question, just a plea for using HTML sanely...